# php accessing form variables dynamically

Tags: php, html, forms

I have some repetitive form field variables and want to put them into variable after POST.

```
$item_code1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['item_code1'] );
$units1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['units1'] );
$qty1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['qty1'] );
$size1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['size1'] );
$make1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['make1'] );
$finish1 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['finish1'] );

$item_code2 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['item_code2'] );
$units2 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['units2'] );
$qty2 = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['qty2'] );
...
```

These set of form variables can be 1 - 10 (or more)
I am passing how many sets of these form variables through a counter

```
$ctr_i = mysql_sanitize( $_POST['ctr_i'] );
```

How do i get the variables like above programatically ?
i mean looping through `$ctr_i`, i want to put all the POST values to PHP variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can create an array of element maybe.

Comment: have you `extract()` function? tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
foeach($_POST as $key => $val){
 $$key = mysql_sanitize($val);
}
?>
```

Comment: But what if the first letter of `$key` is a number?

Comment: [The variable name can't start with a number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) so what happens when `$$key` is created when first letter of `$key` is a number (0-9)

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167: then my answer will be incorrect, but who use numbers?

Comment: umm..  mysql_sanitize fails on some array fields i have.. any sol??

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the below:

```
$post = $_POST;
$post = array_map('mysql_sanitize', $post);
extract($post);
```

After this you will have set of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you have input arrays in your html page like

```
<input type="text" name="field[]" />
<input type="text" name="field[]" />
<input type="text" name="field[]" />
```

Then you can collect all the values on the php side by

```
$field = $_POST['field'];

foreach($field as $a_field)
{
  echo $a_field;
}
```